# OpenGL texture not rendering if it's currently active

Tags: qt, opengl

I was using QOpenGLWidget to render textured triangle, the code was looking good but the triangle was always rendering black i had problem with it for two days until i accidentally found out what the title says.

This is the code, the texture gets loaded to default location of **GL_TEXTURE0** and the code will not work unless i call **glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)** at the end, **GL_TEXTURE1** is just an example it can be any other texture slot except the one where texture actually is. Without the call the object will be black.

```
    QImage ready;
    QImage image("C:/Users/Gamer/Desktop/New folder/ring.jpg");
    ready = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888);


    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program.programId(), "samp"), 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ready.width(), ready.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ready.constBits());
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1)
```

I've tried some tests, creating multiple textures and displaying them all at once, the last active texture was always black unless i activate some other unoccupied slot.

I don't know what to make of this, i'm begginer in OpenGL and Qt but this doesn't sound right.

**EDIT:**

Main function

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QSurfaceFormat>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setVersion(3, 3);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
    format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
    format.setSamples(4);
    format.setSwapInterval(0);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Widget code

```
#include "openglwidget.h"
#include <QOpenGLShaderProgram>
#include <QImage>
#include <QDebug>

OpenGLWidget::OpenGLWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QOpenGLWidget(parent)
{

}

OpenGLWidget::~OpenGLWidget()
{
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

}

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core::initializeOpenGLFunctions();

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
            0.0f, 0.75f, 0.0f,
            -0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f,
            0.75f, -0.75f, 0.0f,
            0.5f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f
        };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, "C:/Users/Gamer/Desktop/New folder/vertex.vert");
    program.addShaderFromSourceFile(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, "C:/Users/Gamer/Desktop/New folder/fragment.frag");
    program.link();
    program.bind();

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)36);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    QImage ready;
    QImage image("C:/Users/Gamer/Desktop/New folder/ring.jpg");
    ready = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGBA8888);


    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program.programId(), "samp"), 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, ready.width(), ready.height(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ready.constBits());
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);

}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    GLfloat yellow[] = {1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0};

    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, yellow);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}
```

And shaders

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 coord;

out vec2 tc;

void main(void)
{
    tc = coord;
    gl_Position = vec4(pos, 1.0);
}

#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D samp;

in vec2 tc;
out vec4 color;

void main(void)
{
    color = texture(samp, tc);
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you st active unit first, ten you bind txture to it. 
How do you render that, do you supply correct texture unit number (0, 1 etc) to sampler uniform  or what?

Comment: I've just pasted more code to show i do all that you said, but the only difference is making the last call to glActiveTexture, if i comment it triangle gets black with it everything is fine. Also i should mention that i tried using QOpenGLTexture, and the same thing is happening, that is, it's not working without activating another texture unit.

Comment: Well, that looks like your code is binding some other texture (or 0) somehwere else in-between.

Comment: This is just textured triangle there is no some other texture, there is no even in-between, it's simple example with very little code. I tried doing the same with SFML and it works, this is related to Qt but i don't know how.

Comment: Without the relevant code, nobody can tell you. Note that Qt has some abstractions which potentially could interfere here.

Comment: I've just pasted pretty much whole code, i only left out headers and files generated from Qt Creator, if somebody can help that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QOpenGLWidget is a rather complex abstraction which has some side effects which you might not expect. Quoting from the [Qt5 docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#details):

> All rendering happens into an OpenGL framebuffer object. `makeCurrent()` ensure that it is bound in the context. Keep this in mind when creating and binding additional framebuffer objects in the rendering code in `paintGL()`. Never re-bind the framebuffer with ID 0. Instead, call `defaultFramebufferObject()` to get the ID that should be bound.

Now, this in itself isn't an issue. However, looking at the description for the [`initializeGL()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#initializeGL) method (my emphasis):

> There is no need to call `makeCurrent()` because this has already been done when this function is called. **Note however that the framebuffer is not yet available at this stage, so avoid issuing draw calls from here. Defer such calls to `paintGL()` instead.**

Now, this in itself still is not the issue. But: it means that Qt will create the FBO in-between `initializeGL` and the first `paintGL`. Since Qt creates a texture as the color buffer for the FBO, this means it will re-use the currently active texture unit, **and change the texture binding you did establish in `initializeGL`**.

If you, on the other hand set `glActiveTexture` to something other than unit 0, Qt will screw up the binding of that unit, but since you only use unit 0, it will not have any negative effects in your example.

Comment: That would make sense, but i have some questions. How do you know Qt reuses active texture unit

Comment: Another question, after the Qt associates it's texture with FBO i can use that texture unit again for my own textures? As other answer suggested i tried to rebind texture again to the same texture unit in paintGL, and it works. I mean is that safe if Qt uses that unit?

Comment: Well, you can look it up in the source code, if you really want. [`QOpenGLWidget`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/kernel/qopenglwidget.cpp) uses a [`QGLFramebufferObject`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/opengl/qglframebufferobject.cpp) which in itself [creates and binds a texture](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/opengl/qglframebufferobject.cpp#n501) when it is initialized. The fact that it changes that texture binding doesn't mean that you can't use that texture unit. It doesn;t consume any texture units, it just uses a texture.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind the texture to the texture unit before drawing.  Texture unit state is not part of program state, unlike uniforms.  It is unusual to try and set texture unit state during program startup, that would require allocating different texture units to each program (not out of the question, it's just not the way things are normally done).

Add the following line to `paintGL`, before the draw call:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
```